# Ringing volume control while play sound using AudioServicesPlaySystemSound

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, avaudioplayer

I play default /Library/Ringtones provided by Apple

```
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);
```

The sound play perfectly but now I want to increase and decrease volume from my application.

I have used below code

```
  musicPlayer = [MPMusicPlayerController applicationMusicPlayer];
  musicPlayer.volume = 0.0625;
```

But this is deprecated in iOS7.0. I want to run app in latest iOS 8.0

Is there any way that I can do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the following code with work perfectly in iOS8:

```
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];        
        NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"file.mp3"]
        AVAudioPlayer *player = [[[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:nil] autorelease];
        player.volume = 1.0f;
        [player prepareToPlay];
        [player setNumberOfLoops:0];
        [player play];
```

Comment: What are you passing in path? Are you playing file from bundle or System sound file?

Comment: Dhaval i use an mp3 from bundle :NSArray *paths                  = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentsDirectory    = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *path                  = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"file.mp3"];